# golang - can't seem to drop http connections

Tags: http, go, connection

I'm trying to measure successive load times of a URL, but have been unable to drop an http connection and start fresh with each measurement. With this code...

```
func getloadtime (url string) float64 {

    // setup client
    tr := &http.Transport{
        DisableKeepAlives: true}
    client := &http.Client{Transport:tr}

    // page load and measure
    start := time.Now()
    _, _ = client.Get(url)

    return(time.Since(start).Seconds())
}

func main () {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        fmt.Println(getloadtime("http://www.google.com"))
    }
}
```

I get measurements like this:

```
2.75
0.13
0.09
0.12
0.115
```

So it appears the http connection is being maintained from the initial load since the subsequent loads are much faster. I have also tried setting "Connection" to "Close" in the header, but get the same results:

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
req.Header.Set("Connection", "close")
_, _ := client.Do(req)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not measuring what you think you are. Not only does your first example open a new connection every time, but it leaks the connections after returning. Never discard an `http.Transport`, or you will leak connections. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to get consistent results from the page load for stress-testing purposes (this is a simplified version - ultimately will be from multiple processes), so I am trying to simulate/create a new connection every time (and close it properly). Clearly something is being maintained in the pageload measurements #2-#5 within the loop. I'm assuming it is using the same connection... but can't tell.

Comment: It can't possibly be using the same connection, because you're using a new Transport every time. I would guess it's your resolver cache making the difference. Rather than guessing, inspect the actual connections being made. There is also `Request.Close` field to set the header automatically.

Comment: Yes, that's why I had put the Transport in the function, thinking it would create a new one each call (new to this) to recreate the overhead from zero. The resolver cache is something to explore, although I get similar results if I execute the code over and over, so whatever is being cached is being released after each execution, and it seems like any kind of DNS caching would be maintained beyond execution of the code. Hmmm......

Comment: One other note...same results on both Windows & Ubuntu.

Comment: and from a macOS system: `0.105452258
0.103022324
0.237812677
0.107968977
0.094626029`. Don't guess, make sure you're measuring exactly what you want to measure.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to assign the response from the GET to a variable and then close the connection with `response.Body.Close()`

```
func getloadtime (url string) float64 {

    // setup client
    tr := &http.Transport{
        DisableKeepAlives: true}
    client := &http.Client{Transport:tr}

    // page load and measure
    start := time.Now()
    response, _ := client.Get(url)
    response.Body.Close()

    return(time.Since(start).Seconds())
}
```

Comment: I did try this.... same results though, the first measurement is substantially longer.

Comment: Oh ok, know I get it, could be resolving the hostname the cause for the first one to take longer? You can test it with a IP address and see if the first one still taking more time

Comment: If you're going to do it correctly, you need to check the error first, and you should attempt to consume the response body before closing it. This also has the same problem as the original where it will leak connections in from the `http.Transport`