# How do I drop a net/http https golang connection without returning any values?

Tags: go

Need to drop connections when the ip address is a bad bot. How do I do this?

I've checked this [golang - can't seem to drop http connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46082079/golang-cant-seem-to-drop-http-connections)

and this will return something.

http.Error(w, "", http.StatusInternalServerError)

I am using https, so I've tried hijack and it does not work because it's http2 and not http 1.1

Any experts here know how to drop a connection without returning anything? Means really drop and not closed etc.

I've already done the firewall using iptables so I'm adding another layer of security with golang that's all. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You want http framewrok to skip any http request on some condition but keep the socket ?

Comment: How about just `return` from the handler?

Comment: `really drop and not closed`, what does it mean to “drop” a connection if you don’t close it?

Comment: This needs some additional information about what you have tried, roughly what your code or an abstract of that looks like, as it's otherwise really hard to understand your exact use case.